# while loop in line 36 won't exit despite fulfilling condition

Tags: python, while-loop

The outer while loop should exit when current_digit and powers[digit_of_powers] both equal 26 but the while-loop doesn't exit as it should.
As a proof of what I'm claiming, see for yourself, the last line never executes. The program is stuck in the stopped while loop.
I'm new to programming so I may do daft mistakes

```
#enter a number in base 10 and find how it's written in choosen base... or at least thats what it should do

import math


def find_powers(num, base, start_num): #stackoverflow experts, this function is not important for my problem
    power = 1                          # power starts as a '1' each iteration
    while start_num + power <= num:
        power *= base

    if start_num != num:
        power /= base
        powers.append(round(math.log(power, base)))
        find_powers(num, base, start_num + power)

num = 7892 #enter choosen number in base 10 here
base = 10 #enter choosen base here. I put ten because its much easier to check the program with a base I'm familiar with
powers = []
find_powers(num, base, 0)
print(powers)
print('')

check = 0             #this script is not necessary, it's just a way for me to check if it can find the input of the def find_powers function from its output.
for i in powers:      # It if it does then the function still work
    check += base**i
print(check)
print('')

string = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
digits = []
# Two things to check here
# 1. if powers[i] misses a digit or not.
#          If it does, digits.append(0)
# 2. How many times the same power comes (it'll always be in row)

digit_of_powers = 0
while digit_of_powers != len(powers):
    digit_of_powers += 1
    print('digits_of_powers = ' + str(digit_of_powers))
    current_digit = powers[digit_of_powers]
    print('current_digit = ' + str(current_digit))
    print('powers[digit_of_powers] = ' + str(powers[digit_of_powers]))
    print('')
    digit_thatll_go_in_digits = 1

    while current_digit == powers[digit_of_powers]:
        digit_thatll_go_in_digits += 1
        digit_of_powers += 1
        print('digit_thatll_go_in_digits = ' + str(digit_thatll_go_in_digits))
        print('digits_of_powers = ' + str(digit_of_powers))
        print(digits)
        print('while ' + str(digit_of_powers) + ' != ' + str(len(powers)))
        print('while ' + str(current_digit) + ' == ' + str(powers[digit_of_powers]))
        print('')

    digits.append(digit_thatll_go_in_digits)
    print('fin du while')
    print('')

print('this last line never executes for some reason')
```

Comment: is `fin du while` being printed? If not: you need to exit the inner while-loop.

Comment: 'fin du while' is not being printed either, but I figured out it must be because the while loop condition is not being fulfilled anymore, it's also a problem then?
I have no idea how to go on about this

Comment: Please use correct upper case letters; e.g. in the beginning of each sentence. E.g. your title of the question. Also use correct PEP8 code formating and break each line round about the 80th char. This make it easier for possible helpers to read your question and your code. You have to help us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are increasing (conditionally) `digit_of_powers` twice, but condition is exact value `while digit_of_powers != len(powers):` (not equal)

It means that your code can jump over this condition and run further.
For example, if `len(powers) == 10`, `digit_of_powers + 1 + 1` will increase from 9 to 11 and can be never the same.

Try this:
`while digit_of_powers <= len(powers):` (if it starts with 1)
or
`while digit_of_powers < len(powers):` (if it starts with 0)